# How alter pgfplots 3D surface plot to look better

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to use TikZ/pgf to produce the following 3D graphic, which consists of:

- a plot of the function f(x, y) = x y/(x^2 + y^2) when (x, y) != (0,0) and f(0,0)=0;
- the intersection of the plane y = x with the surface, that is, the line with equation y = x, z = 1/2 but with the point (0, 0, 1/2) omitted;
- the origin; and
- at least the positive portion of the x-, y-, and z-axes.

[image: Mathematica plot]

That graphic was created with Mathematica and uses a viewpoint (2.85216, 1.62152, 0.828166) in (r,θ, φ) sperical coordinates (where the angles are in radians, not degrees).

My `pgfplots` attempt uses the code below and produces the graphic shown after that.

*Question*: How can I alter the `pgfplots` code so as to closely resemble the Mathematica graphic so that it:

1. uses essentially the same viewpoint (and so the same axes orientation);
2. omits contour rules on the surface;
3. has the break at the z-axis on the line y = x, z = 1/2;
4. uses a more convincing point at the origin; and
5. avoids the "jaggies" in the surface near the z-axis.

Re 5., I did try to increase the `samples` value, but doing so causes a `TeX capacity exceeded` error!

My `pgfplot` output:

[image: pgfplot]

My code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% Define a grayscale colormap
\pgfplotsset{
    colormap={grayscale}{[1pt] rgb255(0pt)=(0,0,0); rgb255(1000pt)=(255,255,255)}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view={75.833}{35.3489},
    axis lines=center, 
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
    ticks=none, 
    domain=-1:1, y domain=-1:1,
    samples=50, % need to avoid "jaggies"
    z buffer=sort,
    clip=false,
    xmin=-1, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1, zmin=-1, zmax=1.5, 
    colormap name=grayscale, 
    xlabel style={anchor=north west}, ylabel style={anchor=north west},
    zlabel style={anchor=south},
    ]
    % Surface plot
    \addplot3[surf, shader=faceted interp, opacity=0.7] 
        {x != 0 || y != 0 ? (x*y)/(x^2 + y^2) : 0};
    % Point at the origin
    \addplot3[mark=*, mark size=1,mark options={color=black}] coordinates {(0, 0, 0)};
    % Curve of intersection of plane and surface
    \addplot3[samples=20, samples y=0, thick, color=black] 
        ({x}, {x}, {1/2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

[image]

[image: update]

I modified the code according to @murray 's numerous comments.  There are two ways of representing the surface: either using polar coordinates for the domain of definition, or using normal ones.  The former deals ideally with the singularity at the origin since it respects it.  The latter sticks to the initial definition of the function but struggles with its behavior around (0, 0).

For the latter, the main modifications with respect to the initial answer are the following:

- the surface is split in two (*y<0* and *y>0* respectively)
- borders are added for a better understanding of the surface
- axes are drawn separately (as TikZ segments).

The order of the various graphical elements counts.

**Remark**
Below, there is an image obtained using `matplotlib` with computations based on a 10000x10000 grid. The surface can never by smooth around the origin with the latter point of view.

[image]

**New code for the drawing using polar coordinates for the domain**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
  
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

 \pgfplotsset{
    colormap={cmpgray}{rgb255=(221,221,221) rgb255=(54,54,54)}
} 
\xdefinecolor{axisRGB}{RGB}{128, 30, 0}  % {128, 128, 145}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    data cs=polar,
    axis lines=none,  % grid=major,
    view={110}{22},
    z buffer=sort,
    clip=false]
    
    % negative Ox axis 
    \draw[axisRGB, thin] (0, 0, 0) -- (-1.8, 0, 0);
    \draw[axisRGB, thin, ->] (0, 0, .02) -- (0, 0, .8)
    node[right, text=black, scale=.7] {$z$};

    \addplot3[
    surf,
    shader=interp,
    domain=0:360, domain y=.02:1.4,
    samples=50, samples y=20,
    opacity=0.95]
    {.5*sin(2*x)};
    
    % negative Oy axis 
    \draw[axisRGB, thin] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, -1.8, 0);
    % negative Oz axis 
    \draw[axisRGB, thin] (0, 0, -.025) -- (0, 0, -.8);
    
    % point at the origin
    \fill[opacity=.7] (0, 0, 0) circle (1.2pt);

    \draw[axisRGB, thin, ->] (0, .02, 0, 0) -- (0, 1.8, 0)
    node[below, text=black, scale=.7] {$y$};
    \draw[axisRGB, thin, ->] (.02, 0, 0) -- (1.8, 0, 0)
    node[below, text=black, scale=.7] {$x$};

    % Intersection curve of surface and plane z=1/2
    \draw[thin] (-1, -1, 1/2) -- (1, 1, 1/2);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**New code for the second drawing**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
 \pgfplotsset{
    colormap={cmpgray}{rgb255=(221,221,221) rgb255=(54,54,54)}
} 
\xdefinecolor{axisRGB}{RGB}{128, 128, 145}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    view={115}{19},
    axis lines=none,  % center, 
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
    ticks=none, 
    z buffer=sort,
    clip=false,
    xmin=-1.3, xmax=1.3,
    ymin=-1.3, ymax=1.3,
    zmin=-1, zmax=1.3, 
    xlabel style={anchor=north west, scale=.8},
    ylabel style={anchor=north west, scale=.8},
    zlabel style={anchor=south, scale=.8},
    ]
    
    % Surface y<0
    \addplot3[
    surf,
    domain=-1:1,
    y domain=-1:-.005,
    samples=55, 
    colormap name=cmpgray,
    shader=interp,  % flat, faceted interp,
    opacity=0.75]
    {x*y/(x^2 + y^2)};

    % Surface y<0 's border
    \addplot3[%
    draw=black, ultra thin,
    domain=-1:1,
    samples y=0]
    (x, -1, {-x/(x*x +1)});
    \addplot3[%
    draw=black, ultra thin,
    domain=-1:1,
    samples y=0]
    (-1, x, {-x/(x*x +1)});

    % negative Ox and Oy axes
    \draw[axisRGB, thin] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, -1.4, 0);
    \draw[axisRGB, thin] (0, 0, 0) -- (-1.4, 0, 0);

    % Point at the origin
    \fill (0, 0, 0) circle (1.2pt);

    % positive Oz axis 
    \draw[axisRGB, thin, ->] (0, 0, .02) -- (0, 0, 1.3)
    node[right, text=black, scale=.7] {$z$};
    
    % Surface y>0
    \addplot3[
    surf,
    domain=-1:1,
    y domain=.005:1,
    samples=55, 
    colormap name=cmpgray, 
    shader=interp,  % flat, faceted interp,
    opacity=0.75]
    {x*y/(x*x + y*y)};

    % positive Oy axis 
    \draw[axisRGB, thin, ->] (0, .02, 0, 0) -- (0, 1.4, 0)
    node[below, text=black, scale=.7] {$y$};

    % negative Oz axis 
    \draw[axisRGB, thin] (0, 0, -.025) -- (0, 0, -1.3);

    % Intersection curve of surface and plane z=1/2
    \draw[thin] (-1, -1, 1/2) -- (1, 1, 1/2);

    % Surface y>0 's border
    \addplot3[%
    draw=black, very thin,
    domain=-1:1,
    samples y=0]
    (x, 1, {x/(x*x +1)});
    \addplot3[%
    draw=black, very thin,
    domain=-1:1,
    samples y=0]
    (1, x, {x/(x*x +1)});

    % positive Ox axis 
    \draw[axisRGB, thin, ->] (.02, 0, 0) -- (1.5, 0, 0)
    node[below, text=black, scale=.7] {$x$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Old answer**

[image]

Something like this; I only changed the point of view, the length of the coordinate axes, and the shader.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    view={115}{15},
    axis lines=center, 
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
    ticks=none, 
    domain=-1:1, y domain=-1:1,
    samples=50, % need to avoid "jaggies"
    z buffer=sort,
    clip=false,
    xmin=-1.3, xmax=1.3,
    ymin=-1.3, ymax=1.3,
    zmin=-1, zmax=1.3, 
    xlabel style={anchor=north west, scale=.8},
    ylabel style={anchor=north west, scale=.8},
    zlabel style={anchor=south, scale=.8},
    ]
    % Surface plot
    \addplot3[
    surf,
    colormap/Blues,  % cool,
    % shader=faceted interp,
    opacity=0.3] 
    {x != 0 || y != 0 ? (x*y)/(x^2 + y^2) : 0};
    
    % Point at the origin
    \addplot3[mark=*, mark size=1,mark options={color=black}]
    coordinates {(0, 0, 0)};
    
    % Curve of intersection of plane and surface
    \addplot3[samples=20, samples y=0, thick, color=black] 
    ({x}, {x}, {1/2});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that help with the viewpoint and the axes. (I'm sticking with the grayscale shading, to allow for faithful printing if done in black-and-white.) Issues remaining: the jaggies in the surface near z=y=0; unwanted contours on the surface; missing break in the line y = x, z = 1/2 around the z-axis; better-looking (more spherical) point at the origin.

Comment: I tried to solve the origin problem by splitting the surface, i.e. by avoiding the singularity.  You can try to go closer to 0... Now, why don't you draw the intersection line with the plane z=-1/2?

Comment: Thanks again! I'm not drawing the intersection z = -1/2 and y = -x because the intersection I have suffices to establish discontinuity of the function at the origin -- the fact I am trying to visualize.

Comment: I see.  In case you are happy with the answer, don't forget to accept it!

Comment: The new code gives a spurious yawning gap in the lower portion of the surface, around the negative z-axis,

Comment: If this was your problem, the representation of the surface around (0,0), then the point of view must be changed.  I updated my answer using polar coordinates; in this way, the nature of the surface is respected: it is a horizontal line moving up and down along the Oz axis.  By the way, the image you provided based on Mathematica had the same problem close to the Oz axis, but since the color is closer to white there, it's not so visible.  And the problem is still there if Cartesian coordinates are used, even if the number of points is very big; the method cannot cope with the singularity.

Comment: I think Mathematica is correctly graphing the surface: there are "crinkles" along the z-axis, but no actual gap in the surface except on the z-axis itself. Mathematica uss adaptive sampling, sampling more densely near singularities. And, in fact, I used Mathematica graphing options `MaxRecursion -> 8, PlotPoints -> 100` to increase the sampling near z=0, so that there is no artifact of a big gap. My understanding is that `pgfplots` can only use fixed-increment sampling and so cannot sample more frequently near the singularity at z=0. (Am I correct about that?)

Comment: Looking at a drawing with `shader=faceted interp`, this is what I understand (fixed sampling with Cartesian coordinates).  The same with Python.  But why are you not happy with the polar representation?  There is no gap there.